# How to use User!UserID to limit the data on Reporting Server

Tags: t-sql, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I've got a 'User' table which maps each user to the data they are allowed to see.

Several future reports will be using this User table and I'd like to proceed with the best approach wto take advantage of the global variable User!UserID.

The exploratory report I've set up uses a stored procedure with a parameter @myUser - in the Sproc the data is INNER JOINED to the User table and in the WHERE clause I limit the data with @myUser like so:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[pr_SSRS_Dly_Data]
            @myUser VARCHAR(50)
AS

SELECT
            x.[Date]
            , x.Product                                                         
            , x.Amount
FROM
            WHReports.dbo.tb_Dly_Data x
            INNER JOIN WHReports.dbo.tb_Users  y                              
                            ON
                            x.CustomerKey = y.CustomerKey
WHERE       1 = CASE WHEN (@myUser = y.LoginName) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

In the report I use this Sproc as the dataset and this then creates the @myUser parameter - in the @myUser parameter's default values section I use the expression User!UserID. Also I make this parameter Hidden.

Is this the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct, I just have 2 small changes:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[pr_SSRS_Dly_Data]
            @myUser VARCHAR(50)
AS

SELECT
            x.[Date]
            , x.Product                                                         
            , x.Amount
FROM
            WHReports.dbo.tb_Dly_Data x
            INNER JOIN WHReports.dbo.tb_Users  y                              
            ON y.CustomerKey = x.CustomerKey
WHERE       @myUser = y.LoginName
```

Comment: looks like there's a mistake in the JOIN aswell - think it might be cartesian; I'll amend one of the aliases

Comment: I've used the structure "WHERE 1 = CASE WHEN ...." in other queries, but not really much need in the above. If I want to make the parameter NULLable maybe using the CASE might be quite elegent i.e adding the following into my original query "WHEN NULL THEN 1"

Comment: Also, for security, you should recheck the parameter in the main data query, not just in the the query that provides the parameters. (Users could use URL access to provide any valid parameter, regardless of their ID.)